# readyState "unknown error" in IE9/IE10..

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

I have the code:

```
var c_iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
c_iframe.setAttribute('src', 'my_domain_and_url');
if (c_iframe.readyState) {
   c_iframe.onreadystatechange = function () { // for old version of IE
   if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
        resize();
      }
   };
} else { // other browsers
    c_iframe.onload = resize;
}
```

this code is working fine for IE edge, but for IE10 and IE9, I am getting

```
SCRIPT16389: Unknown error.
```

for this line:

```
if (c_iframe.readyState) {
```

what am I doing wrong and what do I need?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lt IE 11]><i></i><![endif]-->";
var isIeLessThan11 = (div.getElementsByTagName("i").length == 1);
if (isIeLessThan11) {
    quiz_iframe.onreadystatechange = function () { // for old version of IE
         if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              resize();
         }
    };
 } else { // other browsers
    quiz_iframe.onload = resize;
 }
```

the `c_iframe.readyState` was just undefined whatsoever..